# how to get slim framework working with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, slim

i put these code in my theme file "index.php" 
my php is 5.3.8
already put .htaccess(ship with slim) to wordpress folder and options-permalink is closed.

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$app = new Slim();
$app->get('/', function ($test) {
    echo "hello";
});
$app->run();
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

i run this code, the page is blank
and chrome console show 505 error

Comment: What would be the purpose of combining the two? Additionally, wouldn't there be a concern when it comes to routes and route handling?

Comment: Maybe do some backbone.js or ajax calls?

Answer (score 1):

you can also consider adding slim framework as a plugin, and start calling your required functions from your theme.

Here's a project on Github that does this: https://github.com/Botnary/wp-slim-framework

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `get_header()` and `get_footer()` calls to inside the app->get function. So your index.php file should look like this...

```
<?php
require "Slim/Slim.php";
$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/', function() {     
    get_header();
    echo "hello";
    get_footer();
});

$app->run(); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you modified the .htaccess file ?   Because moving the function shouldn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Including WordPress **wp-load** file within my Slim application opened WP functionality to Slim.

You can also use the REST API from wordpress. So instead of calling the methods as an imported library, you can call them through requests...... a bit dirty, but valid work around.

https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/adding-wordpress-within-slim-3/2213/4

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php include('../../../wp-load.php'); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
$app = new Slim();
$app->get('/', function ($test) {
    echo "hello";
});
$app->run();
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```